# How can I switch bottomnavigationview fragment to another one that is not a menu item

Tags: java, android, navigation, fragment

I have a bottom navigation view in Activity with 4 menu items (4 different fragments) that switches between them. The question is: how can I go from that menu fragment to another fragment that is not included in bottomnavigationview (deeper fragment hierarchy). I am using Android Navigation Framework to switch between fragments.

Comment: you could programmatically do it, right? like whenever you want you can dynamically add a fragment into a container

Answer (score 0):

You could use a navigation drawer or tabs as well.

You can find more info [here](https://material.io/design/navigation/understanding-navigation.html)